# Using COUNT in GQL

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, gql

I find GQL in GCP very limited in functionality and inconvenient.  I've spent quite a bit of time to find the equivalent of this simple SQL query in GQL to no avail:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Account WHERE accountToken IS NOT null
```

Any suggestions as how to go about this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Datastore Statistics" tab (the link right under the Datastore Viewer), choose "Display Statistics for: (your entity type)" and it will show you the total number of entities; however, this is not the freshest view of the data (updated "at least once per day").

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/console/managing-datastore#viewing_statistics) you can read more about Datastore Statistics.

Comment: This is definitely a good start. But it doesn't allow you filter though. For example, Id like to be able to determine how many of an entity type are essentially orphaned and no longer needed.